# Creating summary stats based on deciles of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, summary

I have a cross-sectional dataset. I have many variables including "wealth". I have a decile dummy which divides wealth into 10 groups using the following

```
df['decile'] = df['wealth'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, labels=False))
```

My df (very important to point out that some variables have NaNs).

```
ID   wealth   age   income   ... many many variables..  decile 
A    10000    30     4000                                  5
B       10    19      500                                  1
C  1000000    37     6000                                  9
D     2842    22       0                                   4
E   399932    44     NaN                                   8
F     2344    19       0                                   4
G     5000    18       0                                   4
H
I
..
```

I want to create a summary stat of variables of my choosing for the bottom decile `decile=0` and the top decile `decile=9`, and display `mean`, `median` and `std`.

desired output

```
          bottom decile           top decile         difference in means
        mean  median  std      mean  median  std         
wealth  ..     ..      ..       ..     ..     ..             .. *** (if statistically significant)
age     ..     ..      ..       ..     ..     ..             .. **
income  ..     ..      ..       ..     ..     ..
..
..
..
```

Is there a easy way to do this using python, instead of having to calculate individually?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
df.groupby('decile').describe().T
```

And you get an output like this

[image]